# Sum only unique property values based on key

Tags: javascript, unique, reduce

I have achieved the result I was after but I'm sure I've made a meal of it. Hoping for an improved solution.

How can I sum the values of a property in an array of objects, but only where another property is unique.

[image]

The result from the above should be 16. aaa appears twice, so should only be counted once

Here is my solution

```
const uniqueArray = []

Object.keys(group).forEach(key => {
  if (uniqueArray.find(k => k.field === key)) return 0
  uniqueArray.push(group[key][0])
})

const totalQuantity = uniqueArray.reduce(
  (accum, item) => accum + item.quantity,
  0,
)
```

Hope this is clear. I'm creating a new array on the first object in the grouped array. Then using the reduce on the unique array.

Comment: What exactly is the structure of `group` in your example?

Comment: Please show the original input in form of javascript object.

Comment: And also tell the expected output